# Showing that functions in the real numbers form rings under pointwise addition and multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, ring-theory

Let $F(\mathbb{R})$ be the set of all functions $f : \mathbb{R} → \mathbb{R}$. Define pointwise addition and multiplication as follows. For any $f$ and $g$ in $F(\mathbb{R})$ let:

(i) $(f + g)(s) = f(x) + g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

(ii) $(f · g)(s) = f(x) · g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Prove that $F(\mathbb{R})$ forms a ring under these two operations.

I know the axioms of rings that I need to show hold for this to be true. My question is, when I am showing closure for instance,

$(f + g)(s) +(f + g)(t) = f(x) + g(x)+ f(y) + g(y) \in \mathbb{R}$ and

$(f · g)(s)·(f · g)(t) = f(x) · g(x) · f(y) · g(y) \in \mathbb{R}$

is this the correct way to apply the axioms? My book was very general about the definition of a ring. The whole pointwise notation versus the definition is confusing me. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Should $R$ be $\mathbb R$ perhaps? (This is done by `\mathbb {R}`.)

Comment: @gebruiker Ah yes. We are working with just the real numbers in this problem.

Comment: In that case I would recommend you [edit] your post so that it says that.

Comment: Your last two displayed equations don't make a lot of sense. In proving this, when would you ever need different arguments $s,t$? (You don't.) And then, what are these equations supposed to mean? that the equations are true for all $s,t,x,y$, and for all $f,g$??? That's obviously false.

Comment: Is it a typo? On (i), it should be "$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$".

Comment: I thought it was a typo but my instructor is bad about emailing back and I figured she wouldn't have made it twice. @hermes

Comment: It must be wrong. $s$ has no use here. Read my proof and you will understand why. Your instructor could be busy.

Comment: @hermes Your proof was very helpful and that's how I was looking at it if $s$ was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For closure of addition, since for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $f(x)+g(x)\in \Bbb{R}$, $f(x)+g(x)$ is well defined and so $(f+g)(x)\in F(\Bbb{R})$.

Likewise for closure of multiplication, since for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$, $f(x)\cdot g(x)\in \Bbb{R}$, $f(x)\cdot g(x)$ is well defined and so $(f\cdot g)(x)\in F(\Bbb{R})$.

Clearly ring axiom like commutative, assiciative and distributive laws for addition and multiplication holds for $F(\Bbb{R})$ since real numbers hold such laws.

For example to prove commutativity, for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$
$$
(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)=g(x)+f(x)=(g+f)(x)
$$
To prove associativity, for any $x\in\Bbb{R}$
$$
(f+(g+h))(x)=f(x)+(g(x)+h(x))=(f(x)+g(x))+h(x)=((f+g)+h)(x)
$$
$f(x)=0$ is the additive zero in $F(\Bbb{R})$. $f(x)=1$ is the multiplicative unity in $F(\Bbb{R})$. $-f(x)$ is the additive inverse for $f(x)$ in $F(\Bbb{R})$.

Comment: How would you show associativity or commutivity? Would you utilize $(f+g)(x)$ and $(f+g)(y)$?

Comment: You got it man.

Answer (score 3):

More generally, if $X$ is a set and $R$ is a ring, then the set of all functions $X \to R$ with pointwise operations is a ring. This ring is commutative iff $R$ is commutative.

The proof of this more general fact should be exactly the same as the one you gave for $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

It is useful to try to distill examples into their essential features. In your example, the fact that the domain of the functions is $\mathbb R$ is immaterial but the fact that the codomain is a ring is essential.