# Proof that the evaluation functional is always linear

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I have a very basic question regarding the proof of linearity of the evaluation functional in a Hilbert space $\mathbb{H}$. For $f,g\in \mathbb{H}$ and $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$ we have 
$$
\delta_x(\alpha f+\beta g) = (\alpha f+\beta g)(x) = \alpha f(x) + \beta g(x) = \alpha\delta_x(f)+\beta\delta_x(g)
$$

**QUESTION:**

Why can we go from $(\alpha f+\beta g)(x)$ to $\alpha f(x) + \beta g(x)$? Obviously, it is related to the fact that $\mathbb{H}$ is a linear space.

Comment: This is how sum of two functions is defined. It is not because of the linearity of $\mathbb{H}$.

Comment: @Anurag A Thank you for the reply! Could you elaborate a bit on this or give some reference?

Comment: look for pointwise addition of functions over a ring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $f,g\in H$ and $\alpha\in{\bf R}$, $\alpha f$ is a function *defined* by
$$
(\alpha f)(x):=\alpha (f(x))
$$
and $f+g$ is a function *defined* by
$$
(f+g)(x):=f(x)+g(x).
$$

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So it's just a definition, nothing more, nothing less?

Comment: Exactly. $                     \quad\quad$

Comment: So like here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1530848/showing-that-functions-in-the-real-numbers-form-rings-under-pointwise-addition-a at first they have definitions and then they prove axioms of rings, not in the reverse order.

Comment: Is it necessary that addition and scalar multiplication be defined this way for the set of functions under consideration to be a Hilbert Space? @Konstantin ? Why is it necessary?